# Even after cleanup the memory is not reducing

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a C++ service that receives some events, those are written to a file after getting processed, till that point the messages are in memory, thus i have a big data structure storing the events.

Once the write is done, i do a cleanup of all the structures storing the memory, but even after that the memory is not coming down. I have all shared pointers, so eventually those should be cleanup some time even if i am missing something, but even that is not happening.

I ran valgrind on the service but it is not showing any memory leaks. 
I wanted to check if there is some way that i can check, where the memory is getting occupied?

Comment: It sounds like you have a somewhat complex application in place, with problems that may or may not come from a single source. It's going to be hard to give you any help other than high level, generic advice about memory management...

Comment: How are you determining that your memory use is not decreasing? Some OS monitor? If it's that, then that's probably normal. Memory is generally not released back to the OS.

Comment: I think OS might delay releasing it in anticipation of future allocs, if it would be needed elsewhere it would be released.

Comment: I am determining it using top, the resident memory is what i am monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. Making memory free is almost always a pure efficiency loss and modern systems avoid it.

If the memory isn't needed for something else, the effort of making it free is obviously wasted. If it is needed for something else, it's still wasted because the OS just has to make it used again, undoing the work it did in making it free.

Modern systems directly transition memory from one use to another without making it free in the middle, unless they have no choice.

Comment: Is there any memory pool library that i can use so that i can eliminate this problem of reallocating and releasing the memory each time

Comment: I don't follow, what problem are you talking about?

Comment: @user996808 Assuming you really have no memory leaks: there is no problem here, it is an optimization of the OS memory management :)

Comment: The issue i am seeing is that my virtual memory is increasing, but my resident memory is not. Should i be worried about this, and what the usual causes of these?

Comment: @user996808 Is this a 64-bit process or a 32-bit process? Is the VM consumption increasing at a constant rate? This could indicate a leak in the application.

Comment: This is 64-bit process, i am using boost threadpool which has some memory leak it in. So can this be an issue?

Comment: If it's actually a memory leak, that can be an issue.